# Application Extension vs. Add-in Application Extension

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

Background:
I am tasked with rewriting a 9.3 ArcMap solution based upon a VB6 implementation using an application extension and several forms.  The interface to ArcMap is that this solution needs to find a running instance of ArcMap with a specific map in it and then selects features in a layer in that map.  This will be redone for ArcMap 10.2 using C# and VS2012.  I am new to ArGIS stuff and in someways new to .NET/COM development.  Yes, I know I am in deep. :)

My Question:
I have read the documentation till my head is spinning - such a mixture of versions and FWs between both ESRI and MS.  I cannot decide upon the proper approach.  I feel that I should use a COM based application extension as the heart of the re-write, but I have also seen mentioned an Add-in application extension.  What I don't know is, can I use an Add-in application extension instead of a full blown COM based one?  Do they have the same abilities, or as in Add-in application extension more limited than a COM one? I have seen information that points to add-ins not being as capable as COM based solutions but this seems to be lessening with each release.  To be honest, I don't even know if an Add-in application extension is the same kind of thing as a "traditional" application extension - and I can't find that out from the docks, which frankly, suck.

Additionally, if I AM able to go with an Add-in application extension, how capable are the dockable forms that apparently are part of Add-in land?  In the VB6 Forms that I am replacing, database work using ADO to Oracle is being done.  Would I still be able to do that with these dockable windows?

Comment: Yes, on the ADO-Oracle. I currently do this and it works fine.  And if you separate out your data access, logic and UI, you'll be in a better position to switch between the COM and AddIn.  In fact, I was able to switch a COM ext to AddIn in about 90 minutes on one project with good separation.

Answer (score 2):

Both add-in extensions and traditional COM extensions run in-process, so there is no need to "find a running instance of ArcMap", as they will be hooked in by nature. Add-Ins do have some limitations that COM components don't, which [this ArcGIS forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/937-Beta-10-Difference-in-capabilities-between-Add-Ins-and-COM-Extensions?p=3147&viewfull=1#post3147) sums up pretty well.

If you want to create a standalone program that *remotely controls* ArcMap, rather than a class library that *runs inside* ArcMap, you would use `IAppROT` to get a handle on a running ArcGIS application object and use `IObjectFactory` when you need to create in-process objects. This (old, but still applicable) help topic has some instruction on this, although it does not discuss `IAppROT`: [How to automate ArcGIS Desktop applications](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/56eba175-54c1-46b4-801a-fc968e582581.htm)

From your description of just needing to be able to select features in the map, I would suggest trying to use an ArcMap add-in, as they are a lot easier to get up and running with, and deployment is also much simpler. There are some quirks I have discovered, but there is a lot of info on this very site to start from.

Lastly see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17863/753) for some more general .NET/COM programming suggestions as well as a little more background on the differences between add-ins and COM components.